# Spring Login On HTTPS redirects to HTTP after authenticating

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ssl, authentication, https

For some reason my Spring login form loads and posts to https, but then does a 302 to a http page causing an error.  Why won't it stay on https, and set the cookie with https?

**POST /j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9F9847C75A448A14CF631DBBD2F0E6A1; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://example.com/
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 21:30:55 GMT
```

**Config**

```
<http pattern="/services/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="basicAuthAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint">
                    <http-basic/>
                    <intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="ROLE_SERVICE" />
        </http>

       <http auto-config="true">
              <intercept-url pattern="/index.*" access="ROLE_USER" />
              <intercept-url pattern="/welcome.htm" access="ROLE_USER" />
              <intercept-url pattern="/changePassword.htm" access="ROLE_USER" />
              <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
              <intercept-url pattern="/notifications/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
              <intercept-url pattern="/logging/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
              <form-login login-page="/login.htm" default-target-url="/admin/viewInstitutions.htm"
                     authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.htm" />
              <logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" />
       </http>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have similar issue where it redirects back to http. I tried the second answer here but didn't seem to help in my case and wasn't sure where to place requires-channel="https" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add into intercept-url tag `requires-channel="https"` attribute or just set `forceHttps=true` on your authentication entry point
2. You can totaly switch off http for your server

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue on my heroku configuration, at the end it was that **Heroku was finishing the HTTPS connection and sending an HTTP connection** to the app server.

By default the failure and success URL's in Spring Security do not include the server name (ie. `successHandler.defaultTargetUrl='/'` or `successHandler.ajaxSuccessUrl='/login/ajaxSuccess'`).

This means that when the Handler determines the URL to forward to (here):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.java#L69

It will use the request to build an absolute URL, as seen here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/DefaultRedirectStrategy.java#L31

I manage to address the issue by defining the redirectUrls as absolute, for a Grails application (but you can easily convert it to a standard Spring app), it would loook like this:

```
staging {
    grails.serverURL = "https://staging.myapp.com"
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "${grails.serverURL}/"
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.ajaxSuccessUrl = "${grails.serverURL}/login/ajaxSuccess"
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = "${grails.serverURL}/login/authfail?login_error=1"
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.ajaxAuthFailUrl = "${grails.serverURL}/login/authfail?ajax=true"
    ...
}
```